# How do I make a pie chart clickable?

Tags: android, jfreechart, android-canvas, pie-chart

I would like to make the pie chart clickable. I am working on the example published on the website of afreechart(for producing bar chart and pie chart). I am trying to understand it and i would a little bit further by make the pie chart clickable. 
The example can be found here: https://code.google.com/p/afreechart/

## View class

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        bitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);

       inertialMove();


      paintComponent(canvas);
    }

 public  void paintComponent(Canvas canvas) {

        // first determine the size of the chart rendering area...



        Dimension size = getSize();
        RectangleInsets insets = getInsets();
        RectShape available = new RectShape(insets.getLeft(), insets.getTop(),
                size.getWidth() - insets.getLeft() - insets.getRight(),
                size.getHeight() - insets.getTop() - insets.getBottom());

        double drawWidth = available.getWidth();
        double drawHeight = available.getHeight();
        this.scaleX = 1.0;
        this.scaleY = 1.0;

        if (drawWidth < this.minimumDrawWidth) {
            this.scaleX = drawWidth / this.minimumDrawWidth;
            drawWidth = this.minimumDrawWidth;
        }
        else if (drawWidth > this.maximumDrawWidth) {
            this.scaleX = drawWidth / this.maximumDrawWidth;
            drawWidth = this.maximumDrawWidth;
        }

        if (drawHeight < this.minimumDrawHeight) {
            this.scaleY = drawHeight / this.minimumDrawHeight;
            drawHeight = this.minimumDrawHeight;
        }
        else if (drawHeight > this.maximumDrawHeight) {
            this.scaleY = drawHeight / this.maximumDrawHeight;
            drawHeight = this.maximumDrawHeight;
        }

        RectShape chartArea = new RectShape(0.0, 0.0, drawWidth,
                drawHeight);

        this.chart.draw(canvas,chartArea, this.anchor, this.info);

 }
```

## Activity

Then I would like to click on the region (for example the red area) to display a message .
The problem is because i know where the chart is drawing from the total example code from the afreechart website, I could go to every area of different color, click and display an appropriate message BUT THE CHART IS HIDDEN SOMEWHERE (IT IS NOT VISIBLE). The problem is maybe because of the way i used the BITMAP AND THE CANVAS...

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){


          }

            else if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){







                int color = bitmap.getPixel((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
                System.out.println("color =" +color);

                int redValue = Color.red(color);
                int blueValue = Color.blue(color);
                int greenValue = Color.green(color);

                System.out.println("redValue =" +redValue);
                System.out.println("blueValue =" +blueValue);
                System.out.println("greenValue =" +greenValue);





                     if (redValue == 255){
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Is Red", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }


                     if (blueValue == 255){
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Is BLUE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }


                     if (greenValue == 255){
                          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Is GREEN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                //}

            }
            return true; 

        }


    }
```

PLEASE i would be glad to get your help...It is really frustrating because first i am new to android and i could see the right message displayed without actually seeing the chart

Comment: I even to do this in onDraw(Canvas canvas) something like canvas = new Canvas(bitmap) but having the same result. I have run out of idea. The key to this is to understand maybe the way Canvas associated with the created bitmap works...I need your help please

Answer (score 0):

set an `onTouchListener` on the view and do what u are already doing i.e. get the pixel RGB components. Also for recognizing the pie piece the user clicked pass your own color to pie pieces, so that on click u can give detailed description of that pie piece......